# Live USB Boot to 18.10 Login

Tags: live-usb

I was able to create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu 18.10 but when I try to use as Live option, I don't know the logon and password and see no way to create a new one. Can you help?

Comment: @ Celmo : First check the MD5SUM of the downloaded ISO.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron: That’s basically one of the answers to the linked question.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron if you see extremely old posts, update them or post updated answers as needed.

Comment: @David Foerster : MD5SUM is the first step. finding it among all the old garbage is like finding a needle in the haystack, unless like me you were the one that posted it. See what I mean about you guys not reading both threads before voting?

Comment: @muru. Last down vote I got was for a comment about obsolete posts. and I did not even realize you could get a down vote for a true comment. Thanks but I have learned my lesson.

Comment: When I boot my PC to the USB drive with the Squid Ubuntu, I am offered the option to Try Ubuntu or Install it and a link to the Release notes. I select Try and it comes up with a screen "Live Session User" and an option for "Not Listed". I tried blank password and several other words/variations with and without capitalization. No beuno. Release notes don't mention password.

Comment: @Celmo: I have not yet confirmed my findings for 18.10,  A lot of long time users prefer the LTS releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Celmo: I installed squid to a fresh mkusb persistent flash drive. I was unable to duplicate your problem. Have you tried checking the ISO MD5SUM? The How-to-Geek MD5SUM instructions: https://www.howtogeek.com/246332/how-to-verify-a-downloaded-linux-iso-file-wasnt-tampered-with/